# Как исключить из sql запроса несколько записей?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Пишу поиск:

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT `id`,`status`,`live`,`game`,`category`,`title`,`time_published`, `url`
  FROM `news`
  WHERE `status`='1'
  AND `id`<>'70'
  AND `title` LIKE '%$query%'
  order by `time_published` desc");
```

Как из выдачи исключить не только запись с id=70, но и ещё несколько записей?

То есть в строку

```
AND `id`<>'70'
```

нужно передать несколько значений, но как это сделать, чтобы каждый раз не писать *AND...*?

Comment: `id NOT IN(70,45,11,...)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT `id`,`status`,`live`,`game`,`category`,`title`,`time_published`, `url`
  FROM `news`
  WHERE `status`='1'
  AND `id` NOT IN (70, 60, 50, 30, 1)
  AND `title` LIKE '%$query%'
  order by `time_published` desc");
```

Answer (score 6):

Используйте конструкцию NOT IN ()

В вашем примере

```
AND `id` NOT IN ('70', '72')
```

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_and_or.asp

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp